# Add object to nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have initial state as

```
sites = [

{id, name, vehicles[], drivers[]},
{id, name, vehicles[], drivers[]},
{id, name, vehicles[], drivers[]},
{id, name, vehicles[], drivers[]},

];
```

I'm trying to add a vehicle to a given site when selected from a list which is in a component SiteVehcleSelection and the method that handles the selection is:

```
 handleVehicleSelection = (event) => {
    const vehicle = this.props.vehicles.find((v) => v.id === parseInt(event.target.dataset.id, 10));
    this.props.handleVehicleSelection(event, this.state.site.id, {...vehicle});
  };
```

which passes it up to parent SiteList method:

```
  handleVehicleSelection = (event, siteId, vehicle) => {
    this.props.dispatch(siteActions.handleVehicleSelect(siteId, vehicle), event.target.checked);
```

}

called from the SiteList class:

```
export function handleVehicleSelect(siteId, vehicle, cmd){
  return (dispatch) => {
    debugger;
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/accounts/site-vehicle-action/${siteId}/${vehicle.id}/${cmd}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: ''
    }).then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    }).then((json) => {
      if (json.msg === true) {
        dispatch(vehicleSelect(siteId, vehicle));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

which dispatches to this:

```
export function vehicleSelect(siteId, vehicle){
  return {type: actionTypes.ADD_VEHICLE_TO_SITE, siteId, vehicle};
}
```

and my reducer is:

```
 case actionTypes.ADD_VEHICLE_TO_SITE:
    debugger;
    const siteIndex = state.findIndex((site) => site.id === action.siteId);
    console.log(state);
     const newState = [...state.slice(0, siteIndex), {...state[siteIndex], vehicles: [...state[siteIndex].vehicles, action.vehicle],}, ...state.slice(siteIndex +1)];
     console.log(newState);
     return newState;
```

when I log before and after the changes have taken place, the vehicle has been added to the correct site but it does not show/refresh in the view here is the logging of the state before and after.

Before change :

```
0: {drivers: Array(0), id: 1, name: "Site One", vehicles: Array(0)}
1: {drivers: Array(0), id: 2, name: "Site Two", vehicles: Array(0)}
2: {drivers: Array(0), id: 3, name: "Site Three", vehicles: Array(0)}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

After change:

```
0: {drivers: Array(0), id: 1, name: "Site One", vehicles: Array(1)}
1: {drivers: Array(0), id: 2, name: "Site Two", vehicles: Array(0)}
2: {drivers: Array(0), id: 3, name: "Site Three", vehicles: Array(0)}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

can see the first one had the vehicle added correctly and this is the new state but nothing happens on return as if sitesList does not refresh.

Hope this edit helps explain more.

Comment: Can't you do a deep copy of your state, modify the copied state and return it? States are supposed to be immutable.

Comment: Do you want to add the new object to the `items1` array? As far as I can see, you are not doing this. Can you provide your initial and desired state with your `action` or at least `action.site`?

Comment: Yes I would like to add a new object to items1 array.

Comment: Can you give concrete examples to us, please? You can update your question. Just provide the initial/desired state and your action.

Comment: I still can't see the concrete examples. Initial/desired state and the action object you pass. Just provide simple examples for your data, please.

Comment: Hi edited the question hope that explains it in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code will shed some light. I assume you have the corresponding indexes.

```
let state = [
    { id: "id1", name: "name1", items: [{},{}] },
    { id: "id2", name: "name2", items: [{},{}] },
]

function reducer() {
    switch("Action") {
        case ADD_SITE: { // add new element to state
            return [
                ...state,
                payload.site,
            ]
        }

        case ADD_SITE_AT_INDEX: { // add new element to state at index: idx
            return [
                ...state.slice(0, idx),
                payload.newSite,
                ...state.slice(idx)
            ]
        }

        case ADD_ITEM: { // add new item to site with index: idx
            return [
                ...state.slice(0, idx),
                {
                    ...state[idx],
                    items: [
                        ...state[idx].items,
                        payload.newItem
                    ],
                },
                ...state.slice(idx+1)
            ]
        }

        case ADD_ITEM_AT_INDEX: { // add new item to site with index: idx, at item index: item_idx
            return [
                ...state.slice(0, idx),
                {
                    ...state[idx],
                    items: [
                        ...state[idx].items.slice(0, item_idx),
                        payload.newItem,
                        ...state[idx].items.slice(item_idx),
                    ],
                },
                ...state.slice(idx+1)
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the ADD_ITEM part but I get this error
A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `sites.1`. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"ADD_VEHICLE_TO_SITE","siteId":1,"vehicle":{"comments":"N/A","id":1,"make":"Toyota","model":"Carina","registration":"20/1998"}}.

[...state.splice(0, siteIndex), {...state[siteIndex], vehicles: [...state[siteIndex].vehicles, action.vehicle],}, ...state.splice(siteIndex+1)];

Comment: Try using slice instead of splice, updated in the code as well

Comment: I had made the change to slice and as you can see by my edit of the question the vehicle seems to be added to the state but it don't seem to refresh the changes to the Site List view.

Comment: So with the above code, you were able to get the state correctly. For further debbugging, you can check whether the componentWillReceiveProps() of the Component is fired or not. Also, check the final state in the chrome console after the action.

Comment: In siteList compoenentWillReceiveProps() function, if I console.log(nextProps) to the chrome console the result is :

0: {drivers: Array(0), id: 1, name: "Site One", vehicles: Array(1)}
1: {drivers: Array(0), id: 2, name: "Site Two", vehicles: Array(0)}
2: {drivers: Array(0), id: 3, name: "Site Three", vehicles: Array(0)}

which the vehicle seems to be added ok but don't refresh in the app.

Comment: Check after the compoenentWillReceiveProps render is calling or not? Also, verify that you are rendering component from the corresponding props only. Sometimes people make the mistake of getting an internal state from props and when getting new props forgets to update the state. Also, I am assuming you didn't implement shouldComponentUpdate() and didn't use React.PureComponent instead of React.Component

Comment: If possible just update what went wrong so that future users can also comprehend the final solution

Answer (score 0):

let say this is your structure of state with keys (i am giving random name to the keys so i can explain)

```
{
  data:[{id:"some_id",name:"some_name",items1:[{},{}]}]
}
//suppose this is your reducer code.
case ADD_ITEM:
return{
 ...state,
 data: state.data.map(val=>{
   if(val.Id===action.payload.Id){
    return{
   ...val,
   items1:[...val.items1,action.payload.data]
   }
}
return{...val}
})
}
```

here you'll be sending Id and data from the action like:

```
{type:"ADD_ITEM",payload:{Id,data}}
```

where id will be the id of first level object which's array needs to be updated,
and data will be the data you want to add into the array..

Comment: Hi, my initial state is an array not an object. export default function siteReducer(state=[], action) it gets populated with a list.

Comment: I tried this:
 return [...state, state.map(site => {
      if(site.id === action.site.id){
        return {
          ...site, vehicles: [...site.vehicles, action.vehicle]
        }
      }
      return {...site}
    })];
which still gives a mutation error

Comment: try this:
 return (state.map(site => { if(site.id === action.site.id){ return { ...site, vehicles: [...site.vehicles, action.vehicle] } } return {...site} }));

Comment: same issue mutation in dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an object to an array with a given structure, you can do this:

```
Structure
[
  { id, name, items1[{object},{object}]
]
```

copy an existing state and then add a new object to the end of the array.

```
return {
  ...state,
  items1: state.items1.concat(action.newObject),
};
```

or with ES6 spread

```
return {
  ...state,
  items1: [...state.items1, action.newObject],
};
// state: { id, name, items1: [{object},{object},{newObject}] }
```